# What is the best filesystem for my needs in 12.04?

Tags: filesystem, raid, nas

I'm building NAS for my personal use. 3-5 computers as load. Mostly video streaming, upload download of big files 10GB or so(70% of future load), photo editing (20%), office stuff(10%). I'm expecting a big number of files/folders in some folders(1000-5000). I also decided to use this NAS as light duty workstation(for emails, web, news watching) since it will be 24/7 on.

I decided to go with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit desktop version since server version doesn't have GUI.

I'm going to put at work Adaptec RAID 6805 controller and 24 SAS expander. For start, I'll use 8-3TB HDD in Raid 6 (system will be on separated 64G SSD) with possible future raid expansion.

What will be good filesystem to go with? **ext3**, **ext4**, **XFS** or something different?
What gives me the most benefits for my needs?

What about reliability? I read somewhere XFS is not as reliable as ext3, is it myth or reality? Also, what size of blocks should I use on RAID 6 controller?

Please correct me in any statements I did above if wrong. Did I make good choices? I also wanted to mention NAS will mostly work with computers running on Windows OS.

Any input, ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with Ext4, since yours is a typical general-purpose mixed-use scenario. It's mature, well-tested, good performance, and has good tools and *lots* of self-support resources out there, on websites like AskUbuntu.com and UbuntuForums.com, if you every have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

MythTV's filesystem requirements (streaming, large files etc.) look very similar to what you're describing. They have a [wiki page](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/File_storage#File_systems) discussing choosing a filesystem for media storage. Their recommendation is

> In short, a good choice is ext3 or ReiserFS for your system partitions
>   and JFS or XFS for your MythTV storage. If you have a separate /boot
>   partition, ext2 is a good option, since ext3's journal provides little
>   benefit for a partition of this size but consumes a lot of disk space.

(although the wiki page seems to be quite old and since it's been written ext4 has emerged as another viable contender for a media storage filesystem)

Here's [another article](http://mythtv.livejournal.com/9740.html) comparing XFS and other filesystems, wilh links.